# How to validate the input release naming convention in PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation, release

How can I make in PHP the validation of the proper release naming convention of a certain project?

Our naming convention is like this:

`1.0.2` 
`where 1 is major, 0 minor and 2 is bug fixes`

so, if the user input "test123.222.111" will be invalid.

Comment: Where is your current code failing? Welcome to StackOverflow, but please do not use the site as a regex generator: these questions have zero value for future people struggling on the same subject. Try to implement yourself first, and if your code is failing the community will try to understand why.

Comment: If there are no bug fixes yet, is the version `1.0` or `1.0.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

Here `^` and `$` are the anchor characters, marking the start and end of the string(or input in your case). `\d+` represents any digits having length minimum 1. And finally the `\.` represents the dot.

Comment: hi Sabuj, how can I apply it in my php code? sorry I'm new in php

Comment: `if(preg_match("/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/", $input)){...}` more of [preg_match](http://bd1.php.net/preg_match) :-)